# Possible bug in with angular-ui-bootstrap and angular-ui-router (tabset inside nested ui-view)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

**I'm looking for confirmation or possibly a workaround, this is not intended as a bug report**.

**TL;DR** I think I found a bug, not sure which thing it's in. I've got this html:

```
<div ui-view>
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="page">Default</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref=".nestedView">Test</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ui-view>
        <tabset>
            <tab>
                <tab-heading>Example</tab-heading>
                Tab content, blah blah blah
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I get this error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$compile/ctreq?p0=tabset&p1=tab
```

happens with angular 1.3.0+ but not 1.2.9

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0laKNSJGp31q1swQ2jp?p=preview)

---

**Details:**

I think I've found a bug with the combination of angular 1.3.0+, angular-ui-router, and angular-ui-bootstrap.

I've got a nested `ui-view` where the default contains a `<tabset>` from angular-ui-bootstrap. When I navigate away from the default view I get this error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$compile/ctreq?p0=tabset&p1=tab
```

I've narrowed this down as happening in 1.3.0+ (even the beta 1.4.0) but not in 1.2.9.

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/E0laKNSJGp31q1swQ2jp?p=preview

That's set for version 1.3.0 and shows the error in the console when you switch from the `Uno > Tabs` view to the `Uno > No Tabs` view. If you set it to 1.2.9 you'll see it goes away.

This does not appear to impact functionality but it sure is irritating to see that error all the time. For now I'm just going to downgrade my angular version.

---

*SIDE NOTE: I'm really not sure where to submit this bug. My first thought would be to `angular-ui-bootstrap`, but I'm not certain. If anyone is involved in these projects please direct me. Otherwise I'll just put it in both the `angular-ui-router` and `angular-ui-bootstrap` github issues.*

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think SO is not the place to submit bugs. `angular-ui-router` tag will probably get this on the radar of the developers, but this is not so much a question as it is a bug report.

Comment: @NewDev As stated, I'm not sure where to put the bug. I'm not looking to submit this as a bug but rather see if anyone can confirm or find a workaround.

Comment: Are you sure ui.bootstrap even supports 1.3? This issue seems to say that it doesn't since it's still open. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2830

Comment: @MatthewGreen I didn't even think to check that. I just assumed it was up to date with angular's release cycle. Looks like that might be the solution.